# Google Search Console is rendering the home page from our old site without any CSS rather than the new site

Tags: google-search-console, migration, fetch-as-google, render

Recently, my client's hosting provider migrated http://kastenhandelaars.nl to http://indoorhomeline.nl. (both Wordpress websites) Appropriate redirects were placed and we changed the homepage.

Although after the migration, I'm experiencing a rendering issue in Search Console. Google still renders the old domain homepage without the CSS. This old homepage was also migrated to the new domain, but we selected another page after the website migration.

[image]

The fetch and html response also shows the old domain

[image]

What do I need to do to fix this problem? Or what does the hosting provider need to do to resolve this?

Comment: Could be a DNS problem? how long has it been since the migration? Check the servers logs to make sure Google-Bot gets the correct homepage.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is allow time for your DNS changes to be updated across the board. Depending on your TTL (time to live) value for your DNS entry it could take anywhere from a few minutes to several days.

If the issue is still there then I would check the full page HTML. What appears to be happening is that a stylesheet is not loading correctly, check to see if you have a stylesheet path declared as an absolute URL instead of a relative path

IE: `//www.example.com/stylesheet.css` should instead be `/stylesheet.css`

Also try opening each of the stylesheets up in your browser to make sure they can all be accessed. If one or more can't be check to see that they are at the same path in your site root as they are through the URL as depending on how the site is setup and how the migration was done either the stylesheets may not have been copies across correctly or they could be at a different relative location in your site folder structure.